# How do I add Google sheets data vaildation to a column using apps script for cells to only allow colors and hex color codes to be inputted

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

[see image of spreadsheet here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMnbS.png) example: Google sheet cells may only allow "brown", "red", "green" etc. and hex color codes to be inputted e.g #03fca9. How would one go about this using apps script for an entire column? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "to only allow colors and hex color codes to be inputted" Do you mean that users will enter the words "brown", "red", "green" or the equivalent hex codes into the cells in this column? Please summarise the research you've done done on this, and please share a copy of your spreadsheet with an example of a successful outcome.

Comment: @Tedinoz yes, that is correct. currently i have the spreadsheet working so the cells background colour is the value of what is inputted. However, now i need to add data vaildation so that only colours or hex codes can be entered. i have included an image of my spreadsheet. do you have any suggestions?  than k you

Comment: Welcome. Refer `requireValueInList(values)` or `requireValueInRange(range)` (a bit more flexible than a raw list) [doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder#requirevalueinrangerange). The documentation shows the code to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Apps Script for validation but you don't have to. Highlight the target range, select 'Data validation' -> 'Custom formula is' and input the formula below:

```
=REGEXMATCH(A1,"([#0-9a-fA-F]){6}|green|red|blue|purple")
```

The validation will be based on whether the formula evaluates to TRUE. I'm not an expert in REGEX so there might be better options to write this expression. For example, my expression will not reject whitespaces, etc. The downside is that you'll have to list all colour aliases manually. Also, the expression only tests user input against the pattern - there's no way to check if the input is a valid colour.

In code, you can do the same by calling this method of the DataValidationBuilder class to build a rule and apply it to the range

```
var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('A1:A');
var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireFormulaSatisfied('=REGEXMATCH(A1,"([#0-9a-fA-F]){6}|green|red|blue|purple")').build();
range.setDataValidation(rule);
```

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot!

Comment: @twt333 Glad I could help you. If you think my solution solved your issue, could you please mark the question as resolved?